# $interval does not cancel promise right away

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, cancellation

I have a service where I exchange data, in this service I keep a promise created by `$interval`, nothing fancy:

```
$rootScope.recursivePosition = null;
$rootScope.trackMe = function(){
    var extensionName = $state.current.extensionName;
    if ($rootScope.tracking === false) {
        $rootScope.tracking = true;

        $rootScope.recursivePosition = $interval(function(){
            someService.getAllPositions($rootScope.content[extensionName]);
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        $interval.cancel($rootScope.recursivePosition);
        console.log("recursivePosition cancel");
        console.dir($rootScope.recursivePosition);
        $rootScope.tracking = false;
    }

};
```

The thing is, inside that service I have another promise (from `$cordovaGeolocation`) when I cancel the first promise (`$rootScope.recursivePosition`) it still works for a while, like 4 seconds more. Can I control this behavior ?

Comment: Why are you using `$rootScope` in a service?

Comment: @Ankh, my service is called `someService`, I use `$rootScope` to keep track of my promise and to "turn on/off" a service function because I need to turn it off from a lot of places but just turn it on in two.

Comment: The code only cancels the `$interval` when the `trackMe` function gets invoked another time. Nothing "turns off" the $interval when `$rootScope.tracking` is set false.

Comment: @georgeawg yes, me problem is when I call it the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A promise inside a promise can't be cancelled. But a promise derived from that promise can be cancelled.

```
function getAllPositions(x) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var derivedPromise = defer.promise;

    derivedPromise.cancel = function () {
        defer.reject('cancelled');
    });

    $cordovaGeolocation(x)
      .then(function onSuccess(value) {
          defer.resolve(value);
    }).catch(function onReject(error) {
          defer.reject(error);
    });

    return derivedPromise;
};
```

The above example returns a promise derived from the `$cordovaGeolocation` promise. Attached to it is a method named `cancel` which rejects the promise if called before `$cordovaGeolocation` resolves.

Asynchronous operations started by `$cordovaGeolocation` can't be stopped but operations chained from its promise can be cancelled.